# How to single space bibliography ENTRIES (not the space between entries) using package natbib?

Tags: natbib, line-spacing

I'm filing out a template that uses `natbib`.  Need to make the entries themselves single space.

I know about the bibsep command to adjust between entry space (e.g. `\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}`)

just to reiterate, I'm *not* looking to adjust the between-entry space.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Load `setspace` package and put `\singlespacing` before `\bibliography{...}`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a minimal example of code? See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Where can we find this template? Can you give a specific link?